# Redirection to a different server with the same domain

Tags: domain, redirect

If a DNS server redirects `mysrv.domain.io` to the IP `192.168.0.100`, but there is a second server in the network, let's say `192.168.0.101`, that also "reacts" to the Host-Header `mysrv.domain.io`, is it possible to redirect the user from the first server to the second server with the same domain without the DNS server "interfering" and redirecting it again to the first server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at an IP/DNS level.

Only by setting up a one of the machines as a HTTP reverse proxy.

e.g. is host 1 (192.168.0.100) deals with `http://mysrv.domain.io/` and host 2 (192.168.0.100) deals with `http://myserv.domain.io/foo` then you could configure host 1 to forward all traffic for the `/foo` path to host 2.

How you would do this depends on what you are using for your HTTP server on host 1, but things like nginx or apache can be configured to act in this way.